# how to display the web view under image button?

Tags: java, android

I have created the image button as tab menu and I want to show the webview under this tab. Image button works but my destination display in new window. I am a beginner in android. If you guys know, please help me.

This is my MainActivity.java .

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    /*onClick Button Function*/
   // addListeneHomeButton();
   // addListenerLoginButton();
  //  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHomeSelector);
   // button.setFocusable(true);
    //button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Comment: why you putting `intent` in  `onCreate`. what is your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making WebView under button you have to create your own xml design and use it programmatically see below how to use WebViewin your design.

**XML Design.** webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to http://www.google.com" />

  <WebView 
     android:id="@+id/webView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        //... 

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        //... 

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Sohail. But I want to put the three buttons in horizontal.

Comment: @Myat add buttons as your design not problem i have just added webview code you can modify according to your needs and design.and if helps please tick mark.